# SQL Server trigger is stuck on executing

Tags: sql, sql-server, batch-file, sql-server-2014-express

I am trying to run a batch file in a SQL Server trigger to get information from a query and put it in a text file. I am trying to do this because I want to do stuff with the information in that same batch file later on. The problem is that when the trigger is called, it stays stuck on executing.

I have tested the query and batch file call in Microsoft SQL Server Management Studio and they both work but when I call the batch file in the trigger is stays stuck at executing.

Here is my code. First the batch file, then trigger, query the batch file is calling, and my query to test the trigger

```
@echo off
echo start
sqlcmd -S AZ7GH2\SQLEXPRESS -h -1 -i C:\Users\user1\Documents\test3.sql -o C:\Users\user1\Documents\test.txt
echo end
exit
```

SQL Server trigger

```
SET ANSI_NULLS ON
GO
SET QUOTED_IDENTIFIER ON
GO

ALTER TRIGGER [dbo].[ffupdate] 
ON [dbo].[feat] 
AFTER UPDATE
AS
BEGIN
    IF UPDATE (act)
    BEGIN
        EXEC xp_CMDShell 'C:\Users\user1\Documents\ffscript.bat'
    END
END
```

test3.sql (query being called by batch file)

```
:setvar SQLCMDERRORLEVEL 1
SET NOCOUNT ON

USE [dev]

DECLARE @ver INT
SET @ver = CHANGE_TRACKING_CURRENT_VERSION() - 1

CREATE TABLE #ctb(fuid INT)  

INSERT INTO #ctb
    SELECT featid
    FROM CHANGETABLE(CHANGES feat, @ver) AS tb

SELECT fl.flg
FROM fl, #ctb
WHERE fl.fid = #ctb.fuid
GO

:setvar SQLCMDERRORLEVEL 0
SET NOCOUNT OFF
```

Query to test trigger

```
USE [dev]

UPDATE feat
SET act = 0
WHERE featid = 1;
```

I don't know what is wrong. I have looked for an answer and can't find one. Like I said, everything works fine by itself but when put together it stays stuck at executing. Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: Honestly, this looks like a bad idea to start with. Calling `xp_cmdshell` from a trigger means only a sysadmin could `UPDATE` your table. I think we need to understand what your real goal is here and find a (very) different solution. Also, I note you use `DECLARE @CMDSQL VARCHAR(100)` in your trigger, however, you never reference the variable `@CMDSQL` again. Why do you therefore `DECLARE` it?

Comment: @Larnu the CMDSQL is leftover I will edit it out. What different solution would you suggest?

Comment: Nobody can really offer an alternate solution here until we understand what you are trying to do. I totally agree that running a batch file in a trigger is not a good approach. This screams of being an xy problem. http://xyproblem.info/

Comment: When the feat table is updated, I want to run a script to get the latest change and ouput it to a text file.

Comment: Is it an application that is doing the `UPDATE`? I'd suggest doing it in the application, seeing as you don't have access to SSIS or SQL Server Agent.

Comment: Your last explanation proves to me this is an xy problem. Spitting out data to a text file is huge red flag that something has gone wrong in the design of the process. What are you REALLY trying to accomplish? What is the end goal here? My guess is there is a much better way to tackle it.

Comment: No, the update are to be performed by queries

Comment: @SeanLange my end goal is to get the information that is changed and use it somewhere else.

Comment: Then, instead, use a history table and analyse that.

Comment: I agree with @Larnu. Put the data into a table and have your somewhere else logic query that table. You don't want to make your trigger wait on doing things like writing data to external files.

Comment: So would it be better to make it a scheduled batch job instead of calling the batch file every time there is an update?

Comment: You don't need to batch file, if it's simply being used to create a history of your data.

Comment: I want to do some stuff with these data afterwards in a batch file

Comment: Define "do something". Personally, I think you need to ask a new question explaining what you do in your batch file, along with your goals, and how to history your data (probably separate questions, the former after the latter).

Answer (score 0):

You are locking yourself !

You have a trigger on the table **FEAT** , and when you update one row ( session A ) , you create a new session ( session B via the batch ) that try to read some capture information on the table **FEAT** .

Answer (score 0):

For future reference... you might want to consider adding "COMMIT" at the end of your input file to make sure no tables are being locked for change.